# How to save Pdfsharp pdfDocument to a file path

Tags: model-view-controller, pdfsharp

I am using the pdfsharp for my project..

I am trying to save the converted PdfDocument object to a pdf file in a specified path..

i do have this method

```
public static PdfDocument ConvertTiff2Pdf(string docpath)
{
var pdfDoc = Tiff2Pdf(docpath);

            return pdfDoc;

}
```

this will return PdfDocument  and I want to save it to a "C:\temp\docname.pdf" folder..

how can do it with csharp without using the http response..
because i have to first store it on the server then use..
please help me..

Answer (score 5):

Just call the "void Save(string path)" method for your PdfDocument.

You can also save to a MemoryStream if you need both local file and http response. You can copy the stream to a local file and use stream.ToArray() for the http response.

Sample code (http response only) is here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Clock-sample.ashx